# How to import modules correctly in karma?

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I'm using material modules in angular app.
When I'm writing the unit test, karma says the material module is not an Angular component.
e.g.

I import "mat-progress-bar" in app.module.ts file

```
imports" [MatProgressbarModule]
```

and using it in each component.
e.g.

```
a.component.ts:
<mat-progress-bar></mat-progress-bar>
b.component.ts:
<mat-progress-bar></mat-progress-bar>
c.component.ts:
<mat-progress-bar></mat-progress-bar>
```

When I'm writing unit test in .spec.ts file, I should require MatProgressBarModule in each component test js or it will be

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'mat-progress-bar' is not a known element:
```

Is there a way to only require once, for example in "app.module.spec.ts" file and makes me testing it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

you need to import like this

```
import { MaterialModule } from '../../modules/material/material.module';
beforeEach(async(() => {
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ DashboardComponent ],
     imports: [ MaterialModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, 
     BrowserAnimationsModule ],
     providers: [LoaderService, CustomerDataService]
   })
  .compileComponents();
}));
```